# How can I add a title/label supplementary view for each cell in a UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Tags: ios, ios6, flowlayout, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

All examples I've seen use the supplementary view as headers or footers. I need to add a label above and/or below each cell in my flow layout.

At first I thought all I had to do was *register a class for a supplementary view of kind* and then implement *collectionViewForSupplementaryElementOfKindAtIndexPath* and I'd be good to go, but it seems *FlowLayout* out of the box only supports headers and footers.

The apple docs seems to suggest anything more will require a subclassing effort of *FlowLayout*.

Since I don't want to rework the work apple has done for flow layout and since my cells are expected to differ in size, I'd like to extend Flow Layout to support a supp view per cell.

I'm thinking I should be able to accomplish this by subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

But I'm not sure how to tell the flow layout to ask for a supplementary view for each cell.
Simply registering a class for the supp view does not force the layout to invoke *layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind*. As it stands, that is never called in my subclass. I figured if i reg a class for a supp view, it should ask for the sup view for each of the items in my section... this seems to be an incorrect assumption.

I've seen a great custom layout example where the layout was manually managed using NSDictionaries but I'm not sure how to apply that knowledge to the built-in flow layout.

Comment: Could you update your UITableViewCell's to just include a header and footer label? That would be much simpler than managing a bunch of supplementary views.

Comment: @DerrickHathaway yeah that was the initial idea. I was just going to have a label in my UICollectionViewCell that was pinned to the top. But because the cell size is dynamic and the text can be pretty long, sometimes the label was way to big for the size of the cell, so I wanted to try splitting the title label out as a supplementary title label.

Comment: ...there must be a fairly straight forward way to do this

Comment: The only way I can see to do this is like you suggested: subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and provide your own kinds of SupplementaryViews. And if the supplementary labels are fairly significant in size, you may not even be able to do it with flow layout because I don't think that flow layout will respect the space used up by your own custom supplementary views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you'll need to add attributes that describe a reusable view for each cell that you need one for. you can add these attributes for each cell based on the attributes that should already be there for laying out your cells. you can do this in layoutAttributesForElementInRect.

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //first get a copy of all layout attributes that represent the cells. you will be modifying this collection.
    NSMutableArray *allAttributes = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy]; 

    //go through each cell attribute
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect])
    {
        //add a title and a detail supp view for each cell attribute to your copy of all attributes
        [allAttributes addObject:[self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:SomeCellDetailsKind atIndexPath:[attributes indexPath]]];
        [allAttributes addObject:[self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:SomeCellTitleKind atIndexPath:[attributes indexPath]]];
    }

    //return the updated attributes list along with the layout info for the supp views
    return allAttributes;
}

-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*) layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //create a new layout attributes to represent this reusable view
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attrs = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(attrs){

        //get the attributes for the related cell at this index path
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *cellAttrs = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if(kind == SomeCellDetailsKind){
            //position this reusable view relative to the cells frame
            CGRect frame = cellAttrs.frame;
            frame.origin.y += (frame.size.height - _detailHeight);
            frame.size.height = _detailHeight;
            attrs.frame = frame;
        }

        if(kind == SomeCellTitleKind){
            //position this reusable view relative to the cells frame
            CGRect frame = cellAttrs.frame;
            frame.origin.y -= _titleHeight; //+= frame.size.height; //( - frame.size.height;
            frame.size.height = _titleHeight;
            attrs.frame = frame;
        }
    }

    return attrs;
}
```

Then you can implement collectionViewForSupplementaryElementOfKindAtIndexPath to describe what the view should look like.

And like Derrick Hathaway mentioned, the flow layout will not size row heights considering the heights of the supp views so make sure to adjust your min row height on your collection view appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I know this is over a year later but you just helped me solve my problem after 5 hours of attempts!

Comment: @DBoyer have the same issue, how did you solve this problem, above code did not worked for me.

Comment: @kokemomuke There are 2 options: Use section headers/footers, and use a section with a single cell for all your data (this is by far the easiest if you can get away with it). The other is what is suggested above; customizing UICollectionViewFlowLayout. I strongly suggest becoming fluid with customizing UICollectionViewFlowLayout before attempting to add extra supplementary views yourself.

Comment: @kokemomuke I have a few examples I have written https://github.com/DevonBoyer/DBMessagingKit with a few ways interesting ways to use supplementary views for each cell.